# permission error in displaying uploaded image using php

Tags: php, wamp

I am using WAMP server and I want to display the image uploaded on the server..
i have successfully implemented the uploading of image..but while displaying it using -

```
echo ' < img src=\"'.$p.'\" alt=\"Cover\" > ';
```

where $p contains the path of image, i get a broken image. When i right click and select open image in new tab, the following is displayed..

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /"c:/wamp/www/folders/shubhi/My on
>   this server.

Also this error is not showing complete path which should be `"c:/wamp/www/folders/shubhi/My pics/1.jpg"`
But when i print `$p`, it displays the correct location.

What should i do to resolve this? Or is there any other method to display the uploaded image having its location stored in a php variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **absolute path** to display image which is wrong.

To display image on webpage, you need to give **http url to that image** as below

```
$p = 'http://example.com/shubhi/My pics/1.jpg';

echo ' < img src=\"'.$p.'\" alt=\"Cover\" > ';
```

Comment: But what if I have that image in a folder on my system?

Comment: how you access your php page in wampp ?

Comment: By writing localhost/home.php in the address bar of the browser.

Comment: same way you can also browse images

Comment: if i write ..
$p="localhost/1.jpg";
echo ' < img src=\"'.$p.'\" alt=\"Cover\" > ';
then also i get the same error.